# Laravel image not shown on server and working fine on my local machine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

On my local machine project working file but when i uploaded on my server then all images are not shown, and NotFoundHttpException error when i hit full image path to browser.

mypath to project is as

```
/public_html/offlinemall/public
```

And Below is my filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
    'featured' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

And how i get image

```
<img style="height: 480px" src="storage/{{ $ad->avatar }}">
```

In inspect i get full path but when i hit url then i get NotFoundHttpException error.

```
http://compare.theofflinemall.com/storage/featured_image/qzHWpQeSfKjZ6DOS59ROyYboJ1GCvVi6NNVfLtVV.jpeg
```

Comment: Do you have a folder in `public/storage`? If it's not in `/public`, it's not publicly accessible and has to be accessed via a controller.

Comment: @aynber i create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public by php artisan storage:link command

Comment: check your public folder has storage link or not that generate by php artisan storage:link command?

Comment: @MizanurRahmanKhan yes storage link available in public folder.

Comment: By clicking on public storage link you may know is it connect properly or not. After clicking the storage link if it will go to storage link then it will be ok. if not then you need to generate storage link again. you can use file like Storage::url( $ad->avatar);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server can't locate `storage` as path because it uses `public_path`
run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It should work. Also, try to use

```
{{ asset('storage/'.$ad->avatar) }}
```

Comment: not working. i tried in local and working fine there but on my server same error.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it has symbolic issue. Probably you have used storage directory to store images. If you use it you need to create a symbolic link by `php artisan storage:link`. It creates a symbolic directory into your local project's public directory with storage name. When you upload the project on server the symbolic directory won't upload with your project. So, reasonably the browser won't get the path and doesn't show the image. In these perspective there are many **solutions:**

**Solution 1:** ssh key access, if you have your server's ssh key access, login into your server using ssh key, go to your project directory and run the command `php artisan storage:link` it will create the symbolic directory to your project.

**Solution 2:** By creating cron job on the server.

**Solution 3:** By executing php script to create symbolic link. Please go through this link [cron job and php file execution](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel).

**Solution 4:** By changing the root directory of image path in config/filesystem.php. please go through this url [laracast.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/displaying-stored-images-on-shared-hosting?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can change image tag to:

1. `<img src={{ asset('storage/'.$ad->avatar) }} />`
2. `<img src="storage/app/public/{{$ad->avatar) }}" />`
3. `<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/app/public/$ad->avatar")?>"></img>`

Comment: @M Idrees i give project path to /public_html/offlinemall/public so i can not go back from public.

Comment: there is no need to go back from `public`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have done all that try this:

Check your .env file and APP_URL value: it should be https://[yourwebsite.com] - some people forget to change it from the default localhost or provide incorrect URL with an extra folder/subdomain