# image not displaying when hosted on a sever

Tags: laravel

guys am in need of serious help,I have successfully deployed  laravel application on a live server. Everything looks great except the fact that I am unable to display the images that are being uploaded to the /public/img folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel image not shown on server and working fine on my local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680545/laravel-image-not-shown-on-server-and-working-fine-on-my-local-machine)

Comment: no it doesnt. i can run php create link on the sever

Comment: they suggested this but i cant run this php artisan storage:link on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try One of Them

```
{{url::to('/') }}/images/logo.png
{{url('/images/logo.type')}}
{{url('/images/myimage.jpg')}}
```

And Must be checked you image folder have access to get images

Comment: i have tried them they load up the images , but when a post is made its made with a post and i passing in the post id for the image. when i do that it doesnt show.

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('public/img/' . $post->image) }}"  alt="">

Comment: go and hit the exact URL with a directory on server they confirm that you have access of this directory on the server maybe if you get the image they show error called access denied in a logs file

Comment: i solved it with this {{ '/public/img/uploads' . $post->image }}

Answer (score 0):

Try with using asset like this:

```
<img src="{{asset('ur_image_link_in_public_dir')}}" alt="ur_title">
```

For example:

```
<img src="{{asset('img/logo.png')}}" alt="logo">
```

The above example will display **logo.png** from **your_domain.com/img/logo.png**

Don't use *public* in ur link, just remove it from ur URL, then it will work finely.

Comment: thank you , it worked with these {{ '/public/img/uploads' . $post->image }}